# DiscordJS MessageManager is a circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I try to get a message by id in discord.js, but returned MessageManager is a circular dependency and I cannot access any of it's properties.

```
    console.log(channel.messages)
```

Shows:

```
    <ref *2> MessageManager {
        channel: <ref *1> TextChannel {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        guild: Guild { ... }
```

And

```
    channel.messages.fetch(msg_ID)
    .then(msg => {
        console.log(msg)
    })
```

Shows this, but repeated 50 times:

```
    'msg_ID' => <ref *50> Message {
        channelId: 'channel_ID',
        guildId: 'guild_ID',
        id: 'msg_ID',
        createdTimestamp: 1652473636758,
        type: 'DEFAULT',
```

and a bunch of other fields (obviously I changed IDs to `'msg_ID'`, `'channel_ID'` and `'guild_ID'`, normally it returns proper numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is caused by passing `msg_ID` as a Number. Most `discord.js` methods require their input being casted to `String` as specified [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#strings).